# Em um sistema de login, todas as tabelas vão estar conectadas com a tabela de usuario?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, login

Estou criando um sistema para barbearia e gostaria de fazer um sistema de login para cada usuário, onde o usuário cadastraria seu comércio, funcionários, etc.

No meu banco de dados eu tenho a tabela barbeiro e do cliente, entre essas duas tabelas está a tabela de marcação, que liga as duas. Para criar um sistema de login eu vou ter de criar uma tabela chamada de usuário.

Pois bem, essa tabela tem de está ligado com todas as outras tabelas? Pois as informações de um usuário só pode ser vista por este usuário.

Comment: Se uma tabela poderá ser vista apenas pelo próprio usuário então sim, terá que possuir uma referência ao qual usuário ela pertence. A questão é: tanto barbeiro quanto cliente serão usuários? Se sim, como planeja associá-las?

Comment: a tabela barbeiro vai ter as informação  referente ao barbeiro, da mesma forma o cliente, já a tabela marcação vai ter a chave que conecta barbeiro e cliente, contendo a hora marcada, o dia etc... O usuário é quem vai ter a permissão de acessar o programa e fazer a gestão. Essa tabela de usuário vai ter de estar associada tambem com todas as outras? Lembre-se, só o usuario vai entrar no sistema, a pessoa que quer cortar o cabelo não.

Comment: Então usuário, barbeiro e cliente são coisas independentes? Como você definirá a qual usuário pertence a relação? Aquele que cadastrar?

Comment: exatamente, aquele que cadastra. O usuário é o que cadastra, ele q ficara responsável por cadastrar os barbeiros e os clientes.

Comment: Essa pergunta não fez muito sentido pra mim. De padrão nada tá ligado a nada, a não ser que você faça uma query que chama duas tabelas interligadas entre si.

Answer (score -1):

Isso depende do que quer, imagino três situações:

- Clientes podem marcar horários, sendo responsabilidade da aplicação verificar se aquele horário é válido e está disponível. Nesse caso não existira uma tabela usuário, os dados de acesso estariam na tabela cliente. A relação de quem vai cortar o cabelo do cliente estará na tabela marcação, o cliente será quem estiver conectado e a escolha do barbeiro pode ser do cliente ou um aleatório detre os disponíveis
- Os barbeiros são responsáveis por marcar os horários, nesse caso a validação dos horários é importante mas não essencial como na opção anterior, também não é necessário uma tabela usuário, os dados de acesso estariam na tabela barbeiro. A relação de quem vai cortar o cabelo do cliente estará na tabela marcação, o cliente será escolido e o barbeiro será aquele que estiver logado ou então o barbeiro poderá escolher algum outro colega, caso o mesmo esteja ocupado no momento
- Quem cadastra os dados não são os clientes, nem (pelo menos não necessariamente) um barbeiro (talvez uma recepcionista) ou então você quer apenas que tenha um único usuário para o sistema não ficar aberto. Nesse caso ao marcar um corte, o usuário escolherá o barbeiro e o cliente:

  - Mas não é necessário nenhuma relação entre a tabela usuário e as demais, talvez seja útil guardar quem marcou o que, nesse caso até pode ter uma relação entre os usuários e marcações
  - Caso tenha mais de um tipo de funcionário, por exemplo, barbeiros e recepcionistas, talvez deveria ter uma única tabela (funcionário) em vez duas (usuário e barbeiro), sendo esta com uma coluna função, cargo ou algo assim

---

Se é um sistema em que terá usuários que irão cadastrar osdados dos seus comércios, é necessário que as tabelas barbeiros e clientes estejam relacionadas com usuários, porém a mesma não precisa estar relacionada com marcações (apesar de facilitar algumas buscas), se for buscar as marcações de um usuário pode ser feito através da tabela barbeiros

Isso porque um usuário não pode ler, cadastrar, alterar ou excluir dados de outros usuários. Imagina ter 100 clientes no seu sistema, e, do nada, mudar para 0 ou ter 1000 a mais com dados exatamente iguais poluindo a tela e fazendo com que relatórios tenham dados errados

Comment: a tabela barbeiro e cliente não representa o usuário. Essas tabelas só servem para armazenar informações de cada um. A tabela usuário que eu digo é quem vai operar. Vou dar um exemplo: o cara pega o pc, abre o programa, cria uma conta, cadastra os clientes que visitam sua barbearia, cadastra os barbeiros que trabalham lá. Só uma pessoa vai operar, o usuario é a tabela usuário e a minha pergunta é: eu preciso associar essa tabela usuário com as demais tabelas?

Comment: pois entenda: usuário 1: cliente1 as 15h, cliente2 as 21h, cliente3 as 22h || usuário 2: cliente1 13h cliente2 12h cliente3 14h. O usuário um tem clientes marcados e quando ele logar, ele não quer ver na sua agenda clientes de outro usuário.

Comment: Ata, o sistema não é pra uma barbearia específica, mas pra qualquer uma, sendo cada uma delas tendo seus dados, isso não estava claro pra mim. Editei a resposta

Comment: Então não tem outro meio, a tabela usuário vai ter de estar relacionada com barbeiro e cliente?

Comment: Sim, afinal que cliente e que barbeiro é de cada usuário

Comment: Eu pensei em fazer isso, perguntei pq achava que teria uma outra forma mais eficiente. Obrigado amigo pela resposta